# Firebase Admin SDK: How to use listUsers() function as Observable combining recursive calls?

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, firebase-admin

How to use Firebase Admin SDK [`listUsers()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#listusers) function as an RXJS observable?

I can use `from` RXJS function on `listUsers` to return an observable, but the challenge is that `listUsers` returns users in batches. How could these batches of users be retrieved and then merged?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: @Curse: I've read this page but there is no information on how to use listUsers() function as observable is it?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDK function [`listUsers`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#listusers) could be wrapped with a function that returns an `Observable`.

Then `flatMap` and `forkJoin` could be used to combine the recursive function calls into one array of users.

```
import { forkJoin, from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


function myListUsers(maxResults = 1000, pageToken = null) {
  return from(admin.auth().listUsers(1000, pageToken));
}


function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  myListUsers(1000, nextPageToken).pipe(
    flatMap(listUsersResult => forkJoin([
      of(listUsersResult.users),
      listUsersResult.pageToken ? listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken) : of(null)
    ])),
    map( ([userList1, userList2]) => [...userList1, ...userList2])
  )
}


listAllUsers().subscribe(
  allUsers => console.log(allUsers);
)
```

Note that the last array entry will be `null`.